# What is Metro, is it going to replace .NET completely?

Tags: microsoft-metro

Heard that Microsoft is planning to release Metro (http://connect.microsoft.com/metro), calling next generation technologies and some of them said its going to replace .NET, is it true?

How Metro is important for a .NET developer?

Comment: You should try rephrasing your question to be more specific, Metro is not a replacement for .NET since it is just a GUI. I would also recommend remembering that this is a professional site, proper sentence structure and full explanations ensure that future readers are able to find what they are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Metro style is a new type of ux. It will not be replaced and in fact the new windows 8 has two modes. It all depends on the goal of your application. Take a look at this blog it explains it pretty well.

http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/posts/11-09-15/i-know-what-you-re-thinking-and-you-re-wrong.aspx

Let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 1):

Metro is the new GUI, started with Windows Phone 7, prior to that similar interface used in MS Zune player.